# Retrieving Common Access Card (CAC) information from a client

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

So I found some code

```
<cfset x509 = GetPageContext().getRequest().getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate") />


<cfoutput>not before = #x509[1].getNotBefore()#</cfoutput><br/>
<cfoutput>not after = #x509[1].getNotAfter()#<br></cfoutput>
<cfoutput>#ToBase64(x509[1].getEncoded())#<br></cfoutput>
<cfoutput>#x509[1].getIssuerDN()#<br></cfoutput>
<cfoutput>#x509[1].getIssuerX500Principal()#<br></cfoutput>
```

What I want this code to do is display the information from the CAC, instead I am getting an error `Variable X509 is undefined`...

**Edit**

An alternate solution seems to be to use `CGI.CERT_SUBJECT` however I am not exacly sure how to get this variable to be anything other than an empty string. FWIW I am try to get this to work on a standalone coldfusion server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The getAttribute() method returns a NULL variable when the attribute is not found, which is what's happening in this case. You have to see if it's defined before you can display it.

```
<cfif StructKeyExists( variables, "x509" )>
     { Code }
</cfif>
```

On how to get the attribute you're after, I couldn't tell you, but this will prevent the error from occuring.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your web server (I know Apache does this if you set `SSLOptions +StdEnvVars +ExportCertData`), you can get the PEM-encoded cert as an environment variable (i.e., `cgi.ssl_client_cert`) and you can get other info (DN, issuer's DN, etc) as well. [Here's](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_ssl.html) a list of the environment variables.

Comment: `FWIW I am try to get this to work on a standalone coldfusion server` unfortunately it's just the developer edition of ColdFusion, no third party server.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the server is actually requiring/accepting client certs? Like, have you tested with a tool like `openssl s_client` or something? This is taken care of by Apache on my system, so I'm not sure how to do it for a standalone setup.